# I'm having trouble making my Google map draggable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Thanks for any help you can provide! I'm new to Google Maps, and I'm using the RouteOptimize code from API V3. I'm trying to make the resulting route "draggable." Below is part of my code, but I know I'm missing something simple with the directionsDisplay.

```
var rendererOptions = {
draggable: true
};
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        function initialize() {
          directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({panel:document.getElementById('directions_panel')});
          var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: chicago
          }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the [draggable option to the DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)

```
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
    var directionsDisplay;

    function initialize() {
      var rendererOptions = {
        draggable: true,
        panel:document.getElementById('directions_panel')
      };

      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: chicago
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }
```

Comment: Wait! I got the draggable to work by deleting my existing directionsDisplay line and replacing it with the one you provided. Thanks! The only problem I have now is that the map is no longer showing the route summary in the directions_panel. Any idea how I can make the route summary display on my page?

Comment: The directionsDisplay initialization needs to happen inside the initialize function (after the div id="directions_panel" exists).  I didn't notice that you had two places where it was being initialized, see my updated answer.